# How to center fixed-size responsive tiles

Tags: html, css

I need a page with many same fixed-size tiles, covering entire page such that: (1) as many tiles as possible would be displayed in one row, (2) tile would be pushed to next row, if they can't be displayed fully without horizontal scrolling.

I've done that with `display: grid` and `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 210px)` on container with tiles. But I encountered problem: if width of window is not near multiple of tile width, i have an empty space at the right of screen.

I want to center those tiles, but don't know how. Adding auto margin or padding on sides didn't work. Can you suggest how can i do this in simple way with only CSS.

---

Page text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page</title>
<style>
body {
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 210px);
}
section {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
  <section>Tile 01</section>
  <section>Tile 02</section>
  ...
  <section>Tile 16</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Screenshots:

Tiles with ideal window width:
[image: Tiles with ideal window width]

Narrow window width without centering:
[image: Narrow window width without centering]

Desired centering with narrow window:
[image]
Done with `margin: 0px 9% 0px 9%`,
`margin: 0px auto 0px auto` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`justify-content:center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) seems to be what you need:

> The CSS `justify-content` property defines how the browser distributes space between and around content items **along the main-axis** of a flex container, and the **inline axis of a grid** container.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 210px);
  justify-content:center;
}
section {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
  <section>Tile </section>
</main>
```